# Переименовать файлы пдф согласно наименованиям, указанным в эксель файле

Tags: python, pdf, rename

Прошу помощи, не знаю как переименовать файлы пдф согласно списка. В [эксель файле](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f3kI9PULxyypmLKFs8Tgy2NNe-fALJae/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=106434889534507496883&rtpof=true&sd=true)  первый столбец — это название старое пдф файла, а второй столбец - название новое, в которое хочу переименовать.
Пдф файлы [здесь](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/195CKJg4c5t2vlD0oBTlwYg8EsjQ72Nw2?usp=sharing).

Я взяла пример кода, который похож под мою задачу. Но не могу осилить ошибку, которая вылетает при его исполнении. Вот код:

```
Path = r"C:\Users\ua.bondarenko\Desktop\инн11"

def rename_file(file_to_rename, source_file):
    p = Path(file_to_rename)
    filename = p.stem
    wb = xlrd.open_workbook(source_file)
    # excel file to get new filename????
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_index(0)

    for row_num in range(sheet.nrows):
        row_value = sheet.row_values(row_num)
        col = 2 # 'john smith' col number
        if row_value[col] == filename:
            new_filename = f'{row_value[col+1]}'  # format as you want
            p.rename(Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))  # rename
            print("the if was matched!", new_filename, Path(p.parent, new_filename + p.suffix))
            break

def get_paths_in_directory(directory):
    return Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')

def my_func():

    source_file = r'C:\Users\ua.bondarenko\Desktop\2.xls' # excel file to get new filename
    source_directory = r'C:\Users\ua.bondarenko\Desktop\инн11' # directory where your files to rename are.

    # iterate all pdf files in the given directory
    paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
    for file_to_rename in paths:
        rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)

my_func()
```

Вот ошибка:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14932\2121383975.py in <module>
     30         rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)
     31 
---> 32 my_func()

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14932\2121383975.py in my_func()
     26 
     27     # iterate all pdf files in the given directory
---> 28     paths = get_paths_in_directory(source_directory)
     29     for file_to_rename in paths:
     30         rename_file(str(file_to_rename), source_file)

~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_14932\2121383975.py in get_paths_in_directory(directory)
     18 
     19 def get_paths_in_directory(directory):
---> 20     return Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')
     21 
     22 def my_func():

TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Вы видимо хотите использовать объект `Path` из какой-то библиотеки, при этом вы объявили свою переменную с таким же именем `Path` и она вам перекрыла библиотечную функцию. Назовите свою переменную как-то по-другому. Или просто уберите строку `Path =  ...` она вам, похоже, вообще не нужна.

Comment: спасибо, убрала. пробую дорабатывать дальше.

Comment: Пути вы указываете в функции `my_func`. А вот этот код `Path(directory).glob('*.pdf')` он явно в качестве `Path` хочет не строку, а некую функцию, которую вы, видимо, забыли импортировать. А, ну хорошо, если разобрались.